# Dynamic spring data jpa repository query with arbitrary AND clauses

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm using `Spring data jpa repositories`, Got a requirement to give search feature with different fields. Entering fields before search is optional.I have 5 fields say `EmployeeNumber`, `Name`, `Married`,`Profession` and `DateOfBirth`.
Here i need to query only with the given values by user and other fields should be ignored.Ex,

```
Input : EmployeeNumber: ,Name:St,Married: ,Professsion:IT,DateOfBirth: 
Query : Select * from Employee e where Name like 'St%' and Profession like 'IT%';  

Input : EmployeeNumber:10,Name: ,Married: ,Professsion:IT,DateOfBirth:
Query : Select * from Employee e where EmployeeNumber like '10%' and Profession like 'IT%';
```

So here we are considering values entered and querying. In this case, Spring data is having a limitation as mentioned in [this post](http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/java/can-querydsl-part-1-enhance-simplify-existing-spring-data-jpa-repositories/) (**Not scalable and all possible queries should be written**) 
I'm using `Querydsl`, but still the problem exists as `null` fields should be ignored and almost all possible queries need to be developed. In this `case 31 queries`.
what if search fields are `6,7,8...` ??

**What is the best approach to implement search option with optional fields ?**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please note that there might be changes to be done to use the new major version of QueryDSL (4.x) and [querydsl-jpa](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-jpa)

---

In one of our projects, we used `QueryDSL` with `QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>`.

```
  public Predicate createPredicate(DataEntity dataEntity) {
    QDataEntity qDataEntity = QDataEntity.dataEntity;
    BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(dataEntity.getCnsiConsumerNo())) {
      booleanBuilder
        .or(qDataEntity.cnsiConsumerNo.contains(dataEntity.getCnsiConsumerNo()));
    }
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(dataEntity.getCnsiMeterNo())) {
      booleanBuilder.or(qDataEntity.cnsiMeterNo.contains(dataEntity.getCnsiMeterNo()));
    }

    return booleanBuilder.getValue();
  }
```

And we could use this in the repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface DataEntityRepository
  extends DaoRepository<DataEntity, Long> {
```

Where `DaoRepository` is

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface DaoRepository<T, K extends Serializable>
  extends JpaRepository<T, K>,
  QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {
}
```

Because then, you can use repository predicate methods.

```
Iterable<DataEntity> results = dataEntityRepository.findAll(dataEntityPredicateCreator.createPredicate(dataEntity));
```

To get `QClasses`, you need to specify the [QueryDSL APT Maven plugin](https://github.com/querydsl/apt-maven-plugin) in your pom.xml.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
              <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Dependencies are

```
    <!-- querydsl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Or for Gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    generated
}
sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/generated']
configurations {
    querydslapt
}
dependencies {
    // other deps ....
    compile "com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:3.6.3"
    compile "com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:3.6.3:jpa"
}
task generateQueryDSL(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build', description: 'Generates the QueryDSL query types') {
    source = sourceSets.main.java
    classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.querydslapt
    options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-processor", "com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor"
    ]
    destinationDir = sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    source generateQueryDSL.destinationDir
}

compileGeneratedJava {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Comment: We used 3.2.5 version at this time.

Comment: There was also a guide on this subject here (additional info on testing, for example): http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-five-querydsl/ and originally here: http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: Excellent.. It works perfectly fine.. I was not knowing of `BooleanBuilder `.. After a good example with it, Now came to know what Querydsl can do.. Thanks for your valuable time..

Comment: You are welcome, glad to have helped :D Spring Data with QueryDSL is amazing.

Comment: nice project, make jpa usage more easy

Comment: Any changes to the build.gradle config for version QueryDSL ver 4?

Comment: Honestly no idea, although I'm certain that queryDSL has changed its package name since. Hopefully Gradle hasn't broken anything, this Gradle config was a bit trial-error

Answer (score 38):

You can use Specifications that Spring-data gives you out of the box. and be able to use criteria API to build queries programmatically.To support specifications you can extend your repository interface with the JpaSpecificationExecutor interface

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

}
```

The additional interface(JpaSpecificationExecutor ) carries methods that allow you to execute Specifications in a variety of ways.

For example, the findAll method will return all entities that match the specification:

```
List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec);
```

The Specification interface is as follows:

```
public interface Specification<T> {
     Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
            CriteriaBuilder builder);
}
```

Okay, so what is the typical use case? Specifications can easily be used to build an extensible set of predicates on top of an entity that then can be combined and used with JpaRepository without the need to declare a query (method) for every needed combination. Here's an example: Example 2.15. Specifications for a Customer

```
public class CustomerSpecs {
    public static Specification<Customer> isLongTermCustomer() {
        return new Specification<Customer>() {
            public Predicate toPredicate(
                Root<Customer> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                LocalDate date = new LocalDate().minusYears(2);
                return builder.lessThan(root.get('dateField'), date);
            }
        };
    }

    public static Specification<Customer> hasSalesOfMoreThan(MontaryAmount value) {
        return new Specification<Customer>() {
            public Predicate toPredicate(
                Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                // build query here
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You expressed some criteria on a business requirement abstraction level and created executable Specifications. So a client might use a Specification as follows:

```
List customers = customerRepository.findAll(isLongTermCustomer());
```

You can also combine Specification Example 2.17. Combined Specifications

```
    MonetaryAmount amount = new MonetaryAmount(200.0, Currencies.DOLLAR);
    List<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findAll(
        where(isLongTermCustomer()).or(hasSalesOfMoreThan(amount)));
```

> As you can see, Specifications offers some glue-code methods to chain
>   and combine Specifications. Thus extending your data access layer is
>   just a matter of creating new Specification implementations and
>   combining them with ones already existing.

And you can Create Complex Specifications, here is an example

```
public class WorkInProgressSpecification {
    public static Specification<WorkInProgress> findByCriteria(final SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {

        return new Specification<WorkInProgress>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(
                Root<WorkInProgress> root,
                CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

                if (searchCriteria.getView() != null && !searchCriteria.getView().isEmpty()) {
                    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("viewType"), searchCriteria.getView()));
                }
                if (searchCriteria.getFeature() != null && !searchCriteria.getFeature().isEmpty()) {
                    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("title"), searchCriteria.getFeature()));
                }
                if (searchCriteria.getEpic() != null && !searchCriteria.getEpic().isEmpty()) {
                    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("epic"), searchCriteria.getEpic()));
                }
                if (searchCriteria.getPerformingGroup() != null && !searchCriteria.getPerformingGroup().isEmpty()) {
                    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("performingGroup"), searchCriteria.getPerformingGroup()));
                }
                if (searchCriteria.getPlannedStartDate() != null) {
                    System.out.println("searchCriteria.getPlannedStartDate():" + searchCriteria.getPlannedStartDate());
                    predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get("plndStartDate"), searchCriteria.getPlannedStartDate()));
                }
                if (searchCriteria.getPlannedCompletionDate() != null) {
                    predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get("plndComplDate"), searchCriteria.getPlannedCompletionDate()));
                }
                if (searchCriteria.getTeam() != null && !searchCriteria.getTeam().isEmpty()) {
                    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("agileTeam"), searchCriteria.getTeam()));
                }

                return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the [JPA Respositories docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Comment: I am pretty sure you can get a metamodel generated so that you don't need to specify properties with strings.

Comment: You are absolutely right, QueryDSL is worth considering for type-safe queries

Comment: Not even just in QueryDsl, I think you can create a metamodel for the roots in Criteria API. as per the blog post here http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/ they seem to create a metamodel that allows `root.get(WorkInProgress_.agileTeam)` instead of `root.get("agileTeam")`. String are problematic, after all.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.. I'm using Querydsl, so  @EpicPandaForce answer best suites me..

Comment: info about metamodel generation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037593/how-to-generate-jpa-2-0-metamodel

Comment: Avoid hardcoded strings, use Lombok: [link](https://projectlombok.org) @EpicPandaForce

Answer (score 26):

From Spring Data JPA 1.10 there is another option for this is [**Query By Example**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example).
Your repository should implement apart from `JpaRepository` also the [QueryByExampleExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor.html) interface where you get methods like:

```
<S extends T> Iterable<S> findAll(Example<S> example)
```

Then you create the [Example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Example.html) to search for like:

```
Employee e = new Employee();
e.setEmployeeNumber(getEmployeeNumberSomewherFrom());
e.setName(getNameSomewhereFrom());
e.setMarried(getMarriedSomewhereFrom());
e.setProfession(getProfessionSomewhereFrom());
e.setDateOfBirth(getDateOfBirthSomewhereFrom());
```

and then:

```
employeeRepository.findAll(Example.of(e));
```

If some parameters are null they wont be taken in to WHERE clause so you get dynamic queries.

To refine matching of String attributes take a look at [`ExampleMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.matchers)'s

An `ExampleMatcher` which does a case-insensitive `like` is for example:

```
ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().
          withMatcher("profession", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatcher.of(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.CONTAINING).ignoreCase());
```

QBE Examples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/query-by-example

Comment: Query By Example looks very well and suits many cases, but unfortunately it has one disadvantage worth to mention there. It is not possible to define condition like LESS THAN, GREATER THAN, BETWEEN etc. using Query By Example. So you can't define that some date or some number should be in certain borders. It is mentioned in the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) in Limitations section: `Only supports starts/contains/ends/regex matching for strings and exact matching for other property types`.

Comment: QueryByExample also does not do a join if there is one to many relations ships..Like for example i have an entity POST and i have another entiry POSTComments where one post can have many comments .In this case and lets say i am looking for POST having a status active some fields i am searching on POST entity.It first gets all the posts with the criteria and then makes select query onto the child object ..Like Get PostComments where postid is this ..if it selects lets say 100 posts then it makes another 100 selects to get the child entities which seems to be inefficient

Comment: Query By Example also doesn't allow you to search for multiple values for a single field.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the game but the answers here are over complicated... what if you change the fields of your entity? What if you want to support searching over different entities?

You may just use this library: https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter

It will let you run search queries such as:

> */search?filter=* **average**(ratings) **>** 4.5 **and** brand.name **in** ('audi', 'land rover') **and** (year **>** 2018 **or** km **<** 50000) and color **:** 'white' **and** accidents **is empty**

In combination with Spring's Pageable, you will be able to paginate with `&page=11&size=20`