# Dynamic query using JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-repositories

I'm trying to get a  result of a query using JpaRepository, but it doesn't work for me :

```
public interface PeticionRepository extends JpaRepository<Peticion, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select peticion from Peticion peticion where (peticion.codigo like CONCAT(?1, '%') or "
        + "peticion.contacto.direccionGeneral.nombre like CONCAT(?1, '%') or peticion.contacto.poa like CONCAT(?1, '%') or "
        + "peticion.proyecto.nombre like CONCAT (?1, '%') or peticion.datosAdicionales.estado.nombre like CONCAT(?1, '%'))")
    List<Peticion> findByText(String texto);

    List<Peticion> findByFilter(String unidad, String nombreIniciativa, String codigo,
        LocalDate fechaConsejeroDFormat, LocalDate fechaConsejeroHFormat);
}
```

And in other class I need to overwrite the function `findByFilter` where I'm going to create my query:

```
public abstract class JpaPeticionRepository implements PeticionRepository {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "ExterroPU") 
    private EntityManager em; 

    public void setEm(EntityManager em) { 
        this.em = em; 
    } 

    public List<Peticion> findByFilter(String unidad, String nombreIniciativa, String codigo,
        LocalDate fechaConsejeroDFormat, LocalDate fechaConsejeroHFormat) {
        List<Peticion> peticiones = new ArrayList<Peticion>();
        String consulta = "select peticion from Peticion peticion ";
        if(unidad!=null || nombreIniciativa!=null || codigo!=null || fechaConsejeroDFormat!=null || fechaConsejeroHFormat!=null){
            consulta=consulta+" where ";
        }
        if(unidad!=null){
            consulta = consulta+" and peticion.contacto.poa ="+unidad;
        }
        if(nombreIniciativa!=null){
            consulta = consulta+" and peticion.proyecto.nombre ="+nombreIniciativa;
        }
        if(codigo!=null){
            consulta = consulta+" and peticion.codigo ="+codigo;
        }
        if(fechaConsejeroDFormat!=null){
            consulta = consulta+" and peticion.datosAdicionales.firmaConsejero<="+fechaConsejeroDFormat;
        }
        if(fechaConsejeroHFormat!=null){
            consulta = consulta+" and peticion.datosAdicionales.firmaConsejero>="+fechaConsejeroHFormat;
        }

        peticiones = (List<Peticion>) em.createQuery(consulta).getResultList();
        return peticiones;
    }
}
```

This code throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'peticionServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'peticionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'peticionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property filter found for type Peticion!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at com.endesa.mecenz.MecenzApp.main(MecenzApp.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'peticionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property filter found for type Peticion!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 22 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property filter found for type Peticion!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

My peticionServiceImpl service calles that methode, here is its code bellow:

```
public class PeticionServiceImpl implements PeticionService {

    /*..
     */

    @Override
    public List<PeticionDTO> searchFilter( String unidad, String nombreIniciativa, String codigo,
        LocalDate fechaConsejeroDFormat, LocalDate fechaConsejeroHFormat) {
        return peticionMapper.peticionsToPeticionDTOs(peticionRepository.findByFilter( unidad, nombreIniciativa,
            codigo, fechaConsejeroDFormat, fechaConsejeroHFormat));
    }
}
```

The Peticion bean is:

```
/**
* A Peticion.
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "peticion")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Peticion implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "codigo", length = 80)
    private String codigo;

    @ManyToOne
    private Resultados resultado;

    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "otros_resultados", length = 80)
    private String otrosResultados;

    @ManyToOne
    private Proyecto proyecto;

    @ManyToOne
    private Aportacion aportacion;

    @ManyToOne
    private Contacto contacto;

    @ManyToOne
    private DatosAdicionales datosAdicionales;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Resultados getResultado() {
        return resultado;
    }

    public Peticion resultado(Resultados resultados) {
        this.resultado = resultados;
        return this;
    }

    public String getOtrosResultados() {
        return otrosResultados;
    }

    public void setOtrosResultados(String otrosResultados) {
        this.otrosResultados = otrosResultados;
    }

    public void setResultado(Resultados resultados) {
        this.resultado = resultados;
    }

    public Proyecto getProyecto() {
        return proyecto;
    }

    public Peticion proyecto(Proyecto proyecto) {
        this.proyecto = proyecto;
        return this;
    }

    public void setProyecto(Proyecto proyecto) {
        this.proyecto = proyecto;
    }

    public Aportacion getAportacion() {
        return aportacion;
    }

    public Peticion aportacion(Aportacion aportacion) {
        this.aportacion = aportacion;
        return this;
    }

    public void setAportacion(Aportacion aportacion) {
        this.aportacion = aportacion;
    }

    public Contacto getContacto() {
        return contacto;
    }

    public Peticion contacto(Contacto contacto) {
        this.contacto = contacto;
        return this;
    }

    public void setContacto(Contacto contacto) {
        this.contacto = contacto;
    }

    public DatosAdicionales getDatosAdicionales() {
        return datosAdicionales;
    }

    public Peticion datosAdicionales(DatosAdicionales datosAdicionales) {
        this.datosAdicionales = datosAdicionales;
        return this;
    }

    public void setDatosAdicionales(DatosAdicionales datosAdicionales) {
        this.datosAdicionales = datosAdicionales;
    }


    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Peticion peticion = (Peticion) o;
        if(peticion.id == null || id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(id, peticion.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Peticion{" +
            "id=" + id +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what did I miss?

Thank you

Comment: Peticion bean is having a Filter property/field?

Comment: No i searched it too but i didn't found it and i don't understand where does it come from?

Comment: here i put it in my code

Comment: Well, the idea of the findBy is to use it to filter the results by a property/field of your bean. For example you can do a findById or findByContacto. But a findByFilter is not going to work as you don't have a filter field on your bean.

Comment: any reason why you put all of those implicit joins in your JPQL rather than using explicit JOIN?!

Comment: If you want to do something custom you will need to do something similar to the findByText you have there. Using the @Query annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting the solution here.

I didn't use the `JPARepository`, I added the treatment of my request in the `ServiceImpl`, directly injecting the `EntityManager` in this way:
an example taking as filter just unidad (i can add others)

```
public class PeticionServiceImpl implements PeticionService {

/*..
 */
@Inject
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public List<PeticionDTO> searchFilter( String unidad) {
    String consulta = "select peticion from Peticion peticion ";
    if (unidad != null && !"".equals(unidad)) {
        consulta = consulta + " where ";

        if (unidad != null && !"".equals(unidad)) {
            consulta = consulta
                    + " UPPER(translate(peticion.contacto.poa, 'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ', 'aeiouAEIOU')) LIKE UPPER(translate('%"
                    + unidad + "%', 'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ', 'aeiouAEIOU')) ";
            filtro = true;
        }
    }
    peticiones = peticionMapper.peticionsToPeticionDTOs((List<Peticion>) em.createQuery(consulta).getResultList());
    return peticiones;
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

You cant create dynamic queries in JPQL like you want with easy string concatenation.

You have 3 options in Spring Data JPA:

- [QueryDSL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl)
- [Query by Example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)
- [Criteria API (Specifications)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)

There is a nice overview of the 3 methods in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses/)

From this 3 you have two left because Spring Data JPA cant do date aritmethic on Date fields in Query By Example (BTW i wish it could: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-985). Take a look at the Spring Data Blog [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) for these two options.

Answer (score 0):

I think the findByFilter method is a default method of the repository.

By not annotating it will search for a field called filter and implementation is not necessary.

Try changing the name of the method to 'abcdef'

Maybe I can help you this link to customize it.