# JPQL: How to write dynamic where conditions

Tags: criteria, jpql

I am struggling with JPQL dynamic where condition. I tried searching the syntax for the same but coluldn't find one.

in my case if user is passing the name parameter then the select query should be

select * from user where name = 'sanjay'

if user is not passing name parameter then select query should be

```
select * from user
```

Below is my jpql query format which fails when name parameter is not passed.

```
entity_manager.createQuery("select u from user u where u.name = :name").setParameter("name",params[:name]).getResultList()
```

How can i update above JPQL query to support both the cases i.e when the name parameter is passed and when the name parameter is not passed ??

Comment: Use two different queries, or append the where clause if the parameter is there, or use the criteria API, or use QueryDSL.

Comment: Here are your options to have dynamic queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses/

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in JPQL. You even cannot do something like

```
createQuery("select u from user u where u.name = :name OR :name IS NULL")
```

It is not possible. That simple. Use two queries or use the **Criteria API**.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the answer I get when I tries to do like you it is working with some modification.**

In my case I had the problem that my optional parameter was a `List<String>` and the solution was the following:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT *
                FROM ...
                 WHERE (COLUMN_X IN :categories OR COALESCE(:categories, null) IS NULL)"
, nativeQuery = true)
List<Archive> findByCustomCriteria1(@Param("categories") List<String> categories);
```

This way:

- If the **parameter** **has *one or more values*** it is selected by the **left side** of the *OR* operator
- If the **parameter** *categories* **is *null***, meaning that i have to select all values for *COLUMN_X*, will always return TRUE by the **right side** of the *OR* operator

## Why `COALESCE` and why a *null* value inside of it?

### Let's explore the `WHERE` clause in all conditions:

**Case 1:** `categories = null`

```
(COLUMN_X IN null OR COALESCE(null, null) IS NULL)
```

The left part of the *OR* will return false, while the right part of the *OR* will always return true, in fact [`COALESCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rreffunccoalesce.html) will return the first non-null value if present and returns null if all arguments are null.

**Case 2:** `categories = ()`

```
(COLUMN_X IN null OR COALESCE(null, null) IS NULL)
```

JPA will automatically identify an empty list as a null value, hence same result of Case 1.

**Case 3:** `categories = ('ONE_VALUE')`

```
(COLUMN_X IN ('ONE_VALUE') OR COALESCE('ONE_VALUE', null) IS NULL)
```

The left part of the *OR* will return true only for those values for which `COLUMN_X = 'ONE_VALUE'` while the right part of the *OR* will never return true, because it is equals to `'ONE_VALUE' IS NULL` (that is false).

Why the null as second parameter? Well, that's because `COALESCE` needs at least two parameters.

**Case 4:** `categories = ('ONE_VALUE', 'TWO_VALUE')`

```
(COLUMN_X IN ('ONE_VALUE', 'TWO_VALUE') OR COALESCE('ONE_VALUE', 'TWO_VALUE', null) IS NULL)
```

As in Case 3, the left part of the *OR* operator will select only the rows for which `COLUMN_X` is equale to `'ONE_VALUE'` or  `'TWO_VALUE'`.