# QueryDsl with Springboot, gradle and IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, querydsl, lombok

I am trying to use QueryDsl with a Spring boot gradle project. Here is my `build.gradle`. `Q` prefixed entity classes are generated in `build/same/package/as/entities`. I am using intelliJ 2017.x and it could not identify these generated symbols. It would be nice to have these generated `src/main/generated/`.  Also, I could not find any documentation for `:jpa` within dependencies.
Appreciate any help.

```
dependencies {
        compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-root:4.1.4")
        compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.1.4")
        compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4:jpa")
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('/generated')
        generatedSourceDirs += file('/generated')
    }
}
```

Update:
I tried using [ewerk plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.annotation-processor), then the annotation processing for `lombok` fails.

```
plugins {
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.9"
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/28874506/2413303

Comment: I will try that out. Thank you!

Comment: @NaveenBabuE you got  a solution for this? can you post it?