# Spring jpa jpql query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I was wondering if is possible to execute jpql query by a spring jpa repository and be able to use paging as sort feature as it can be donde with *Example* and *Specification*. I would like to do something like:

```
findAll(String jpql, Pageable pageable)
```

QueryByExampleExecutor interface i.e. declare:

```
findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable);
```

JpaSpecificationExecutor interface declare:

```
Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Spring Data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) it should be possible even with native queries. Have a look at example 51:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
  Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Sorting seems also possible as per [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting):

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where u.lastname like ?1%")
  List<User> findByAndSort(String lastname, Sort sort);

  @Query("select u.id, LENGTH(u.firstname) as fn_len from User u where u.lastname like ?1%")
  List<Object[]> findByAsArrayAndSort(String lastname, Sort sort);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but what I was looking for is to create query dynamically and call repository in code,  your alternatives required query already predefined

Comment: Writing JPQL on the fly, can be buggy. JPQL is compiled at runtime but only at the classloading phase, so if you have an error your repository will not load. That's a good security measure. You can try to use Criteria Query instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses