# Multi-Column Search with Spring JPA Specifications

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql, jpa-criteria

I want to create a multi field search in a Spring-Boot back-end. How to do this with a `Specification<T>` ?

**Environment**

```
Springboot
Hibernate
Gradle
Intellij
```

The UI in the front end is a Jquery Datatable. Each column allows a single string search term to be applied. The search terms across more than one column is joined by a `and`.

[image]

I have the filters coming from the front end already getting populated into a Java object.

**Step 1**
Extend JPA Specification executor

```
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<Some, Long>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Some, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
```

**Step2**
Create a new class SomeSpec

This is where I am lost as to what the code looks like it and how it works.

Do I need a method for each column?
What is Root and what is Criteria Builder?
What else is required?

I am rather new at JPA so while I don't need anyone to write the code for me a detailed explanation would be good.

**UPDATE**
It appears QueryDSL is the easier and better way to approach this. I am using Gradle. Do I need to change my build.gradle from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses/28874506#28874506) ?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use QueryDSL, you'll have to write your own specifications. First of all, you need to extend your repository from `JpaSpecificationExecutor` like you did. Make sure to add the generic though (`JpaSpecificationExecutor<Some>`).

After that you'll have to create three specifications (one for each column), in [the Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) they define these specifications as static methods in a class. Basically, creating a specification means that you'll have to subclass `Specification<Some>`, which has only one method to implement, [`toPredicate(Root<Some>, CriteriaQuery<?>, CriteriaBuilder)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html#toPredicate-javax.persistence.criteria.Root-javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery-javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder-).

If you're using Java 8, you can use lambdas to create an anonymous inner class, eg.:

```
 public class SomeSpecs {
     public static Specification<Some> withAddress(String address) {
          return (root, query, builder) -> {
               // ...
          };
     }
 }
```

For the actual implementation, you can use `Root` to get to a specific node, eg. `root.get("address")`. The `CriteriaBuilder` on the other hand is to define the where clause, eg. `builder.equal(..., ...)`.

In your case you want something like this:

```
 public class SomeSpecs {
     public static Specification<Some> withAddress(String address) {
          return (root, query, builder) -> builder.equal(root.get("address"), address);
     }
 }
```

Or alternatively if you want to use a `LIKE` query, you could use:

```
public class SomeSpecs {
     public static Specification<Some> withAddress(String address) {
          return (root, query, builder) -> builder.like(root.get("address"), "%" + address + "%");
     }
 }
```

Now you have to repeat this for the other fields you want to filter on. After that you'll have to use all specifications together (using [`and()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html#and-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-), [`or()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html#or-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-), ...). Then you can use the [`repository.findAll(Specification)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-) method to query based on that specification, for example:

```
public List<Some> getSome(String address, String name, Date date) {
    return repository.findAll(where(withAddress(address))
         .and(withName(name))
         .and(withDate(date));
}
```

You can use static imports to import `withAddress()`, `withName()` and `withDate()` to make it easier to read. The `where()` method can also be statically imported (comes from [`Specification.where()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html#where-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-)).

Be aware though that the method above may have to be tweaked since you don't want to filter on the address field if it's `null`. You could do this by returning `null`, for example:

```
public List<Some> getSome(String address, String name, Date date) {
    return repository.findAll(where(address == null ? null : withAddress(address))
         .and(name == null ? null : withName(name))
         .and(date == null ? null : withDate(date));
}
```

Comment: Which querydsl do I use? com.mysema.querydsl or com.querydsl?

Comment: sure, but if I did want to use it?

Comment: @g00glen00b - Could you please guide me here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57167639/multi-column-search-using-specifications-spring-data-jpa-within-associated-entit?

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using Spring Data's support for QueryDSL as you would get quite a lot without having to write very much code i.e. you would not actually have to write the specifictions.

See here for an overview:

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

> Although this approach is really convenient (you don’t even have to
>   write a single line of implementation code to get the queries
>   executed) it has two drawbacks: first, the number of query methods
>   might grow for larger applications because of - and that’s the second
>   point - **the queries define a fixed set of criterias**. To avoid these
>   two drawbacks, wouldn’t it be cool if you could come up with a set of
>   atomic predicates that you could combine dynamically to build your
>   query?

So essentially your repository becomes:

```
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<Some, Long>,
     PagingAndSortingRepository<Some, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Some>{

}
```

You can also get request parameters automatically bound to a predicate in your Controller:

See here:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/04/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-gosling#querydsl-web-support

SO your Controller would look like:

```
  @Controller
  class SomeController {

    private final SomeRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String index(Model model,
                 @QuerydslPredicate(root = Some.class) Predicate predicate,
                 Pageable pageable) {

      model.addAttribute("data", repository.findAll(predicate, pageable));
      return "index";
    }
  }
```

So with the above in place it is simply a Case of enabling QueryDSL on your project and the UI should now be able to filter, sort and page data by various combinations of criteria.

Comment: I am not sure whether I need to ask a new question framed around QueryDSL or whether the answers here can be tweaked?

Comment: If it's around Gradle then I don't know Gradle but the question you linked to indicates what is required. There's a plgin here also: https://github.com/ewerk/gradle-plugins/tree/master/querydsl-plugin