# How to implement a detailed search query with optional parameters in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I need to find an efficient and logical way to implement a search for a given entity, like `Person`. Suppose that a person has `name`, `surname`, `birthDay`, `birthPlace` etc.

In my REST-API service, the client app can search people by only its `name`, `surname` and mixed them, so all the parameters may be optional. I don't want to make a lot of `if(person.name!=null){em.setParamet(":name",person.name);`....

How can I do this in an intelligent way?

Comment: I would go with query parameters, build a query object and submit that to a dedicated service method `getByQuery`. Then, i would conditionally add parameters (for example, if `query.hasName()`, then add `query.getName()`) to a JPA Criteria Query. Still some mapping is required, but this may be a viable solution.

Comment: Use JPA specifications for this purpose. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970689/multi-column-search-with-spring-jpa-specifications or use Criteria API directly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199433/jpa-criteria-api-with-multiple-parameters

Comment: Thank you, could please just make an answer with an example, in order to get the point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data - Multi-column searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872637/spring-data-multi-column-searches)