# How can I use parameter's method in @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to invoke parameter's method inside `@Query` annotation?

Example:

```
@Query("SELECT user " +
    "FROM User user " +
    "WHERE (?1.getFilter() = '*' OR user.name = ?1)");
List<User> getUsers(UserNameFilter userNameFilter);
```

I know that I can do something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT user " +
    "FROM User user " +
    "WHERE (?1 = '*' OR user.name = ?1)");
List<User> getUsers(String userName);
```

But when a number of filters are increasing it means that I need to change a number of parameters.

Comment: I don't think that's possible this way. You may want to use Criteria Api and pass Filter object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With SpEL you can use Spring bean methods in your queries, for example

```
@Query("select e from MyEntity e where ?#{@myBean.myMethod(#param1)} is true")
List<MyEntity> entities = getEntity(@Param("param1") String param);
```

You can define your bean in any proper way, for example:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    public boolean myMethod(String param) {...}
}
```

Or it can be even the same repo:

```
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Query("select e from MyEntity e where ?#{@myRepo.myMethod(#param1)} is true")
    List<MyEntity> entities = getEntity(@Param("param1") String param);

    default boolean myMethod(String param) {...}
}
```

Also you can use parameter properties in your queries:

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.firstname = ?#{#customer.firstname}")
List<User> findUsersByCustomersFirstname(@Param("customer") Customer customer);
```

Additional info: [1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions), [2](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions), [3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java)

Comment: Is this even possible for Spring JPA query IN ? For instance `select u from User u where u.firstName IN (?#{#customer.firstname})` ?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic Why not? Have you tried it?.. I can't find such in Spring Data JPA project [examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java) but I'm sure that this should work..

Comment: It works but slightly different. You have to change to `select u from User u where u.firstName IN (:#{#customers.![firstName]} )` where `customers` can be a List of Objects.