# How to call SQL dateAdd method using JPA @Query

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1, dateadd

I have to search for row, which is older than 6 months. I have insert time(datetime) as one of the column in my table. 
if it would have been a sql query, it is straight forward like this :-

```
select * from myTable where insertTime<=dateadd(month, -6, getDate());
```

But I am using JPA, so I had to write something like this :-

```
select * from myTable where insertTime<=function('DATEADD',month, -6, function('getDate'));
```

I am not sure how to put month paramater in above query.

I am getting following error on above query

> Error creating bean with name 'myRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query ....

How should I put *month* field in above query? Is it possible through JPA?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [SPeL support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50449383/5380322) you can try to use the following trick:

```
public interface MyEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {

    @Query("select e from MyEntity e where e.createdAt <= ?#{@myEntityRepo.sixMonthsBefore()}")
    List<MyEntity> getAllSixMonthsOld();

    default Instant sixMonthsBefore() {
        return Instant.now().minus(6, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
    }
}
```

Comment: My man you are a genius. I really really needed this in my life.