# SQL between two timestamp

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have table with 2 columns

```
CREATE TABLE booking_schedules (
  date_start    TIMESTAMP
  date_end      TIMESTAMP,
);
```

I need to do SELECT * booking_schedules where TIMESTAMP(parameter from back-end) between date_start and **TIMESTAMP+3 HOUR**
JPA QUERY IS

```
@Query(value = "select bs from BookingSchedule bs :chosenTime between bs.dateStart and :chosenTime1")
    List<BookingSchedule> findAllBookingSchedulesByDateBetweenDateStartAndDateEnd(@Param("chosenTime") Date chosenTime,@Param("chosenTime1") Date chosenTime1);
```

Where **chosenTime is TIMESTAMP and chosenTime1 is TIMESTAMP + 3 HOUR**

In this case Select returns all rows.

So trouble(i think) is to set 2-nd parameter as TIMESTAMP+3 HOUR. Is is possible? If yes then how?Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: i wonder what the GENERATED SQL is, that the JPA provider uses for that JPQL ... maybe looking at it in the log will tell you more

Comment: What is the command to saw that?

Comment: You chose the JPA provider. Perhaps if you consult its documentation ...

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50825188/5380322

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM booking_schedules 
WHERE TIMESTAMP_x between date_start and 
TIMESTAMP_x +
INTERVAL '3 hours'
```

This should work fine