# How to join OneToMany in Spring boot JPA with a complex Where condition?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Consider an `@Entity` over a class having an id and a type which has a **list** which comes using a join operation on another entity.

```
@Entity
class A {

    @Id
    @Column
    Long id;
    
    @Column
    String typeA;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "ref_id")
    // here a where condition
    List<B> listB;
    
}

@Entity
class B {
   @Id
   @Column
   Long id;

   @Column
   String typeB;

   @Column
   Long ref_id;
}
```

the SQL version to populate the listB is -

```
SELECT * FROM B JOIN A ON B.id = A.ID WHERE B.typeB = CONCAT(A.typeA,'_A_')
```

> so A (id : 1, typeA: xx) will be linked to b[(id:2, typeB:
> xx_A_),(id:3,typeB: xx_A_)] and A (id : 1, typeA: yy) will be linked
> to b[(id:2, typeB: yy_A_),(id:3,typeB: yy_A_)]

I couldn't find a way to take property value from A or pass param to @Where annotation.

Comment: Does your SQL version work when you execute it?

Comment: Yes @KeshavramKuduwa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the native query in JPA as follows:

```java
    @Query(value = "your SQL query", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<B> getCustomBList();
```

And this must be into:

```java
@Repository
public interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<B, Long> { }
```

Comment: tried, intellij says @Query is not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about your SQL query but Yes you can use @Param in your custom queries,this question is already answered here [How can I use parameter's method in @Query annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447665/how-can-i-use-parameters-method-in-query-annotation)

Here is how you can use, this is already stated in above question I have stated here for your reference.

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.firstname = ?#{#customer.firstname}")
List<User> findUsersByCustomersFirstname(@Param("customer") Customer customer);
```