# how we can achive dynamic query in spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```
@Query(value = "select ddc.id as skuID,slc.DESCRIPTION as descriptionID from Default_Table ddc JOIN SKU_CONFIG slc ON ddc.id = slc.id ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",countQuery ="select count(*) from Default_Table",nativeQuery = true)

public Page<Object[]> getAllObject(Pageable pageable);
```

Above query is static query.but if i have multiple properties in my domain class and based upon that i want to do pagination sorting .so how i can achieve this by dynamic query in jpa?

Comment: Welcome to SO, maybe you can visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses) to see if it fit your question?