# JPQL whith differne Where parameters (JpaRepository & Spring)

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I generated the where query.
It's always different.
Is there a way to use this WHERE in the @Query for a JPARepository

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE :whereQuery") 
List<Entity> getEntity(@Param("whereQuery") String whereQuery);
```

Comment: No. JPQL would interpret that as a boolean, not a String, and is then compiled. Dynamic queries are done using criteria.

Comment: @BillyFrost criteria I would better do with the EntityManager right?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses

Comment: Specifications is the way to go: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications QueryDSL is no longer maintained.