# Can I create a generic @Query that detects which parameters from URL are not null and make a search only by them with Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-rest

Am I able to create a generic @Query that detects which parameters from URL are not null and make a search only by them instead of creating a method for each parameters combination with Spring Framework?

For example: I have two parameters in my URL; I wanna make only one query that detects the not-null parameters from my URL and pass them to my query, ignoring the nulls (instead of creating a lot of if/else and different queries for different parameters combination).

I created this code which returns a list of countries based on the NOT-NULL parameters the user passed in the URL. Since I have 4 parameters, all the possibilities result in 16 different queries (as I also have a findAll method, that brings all the results when no parameter is defined), and it's boring to create them all the time.

**My controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/countries", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity listCountries(
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
        @RequestParam(value = "twoLetterCode", required = false) String twoLetterCode,
        @RequestParam(value = "threeLetterCode", required = false) String threeLetterCode,
        @RequestParam(value = "nameInPortuguese", required = false) String nameInPortuguese) {
    try {

        List<Country> countryList = null;

        @Autowired
        private CountryRepository countryRepository;

        if (name != null && !name.isEmpty() && !name.equals("")) {
            if (twoLetterCode != null && !twoLetterCode.isEmpty() && !twoLetterCode.equals("")) {
                if (threeLetterCode != null && !threeLetterCode.isEmpty() && !threeLetterCode.equals("")) {
                    if (nameInPortuguese != null && !nameInPortuguese.isEmpty() && !nameInPortuguese.equals("")) {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByNameTwoLetterCodeThreeLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(name, twoLetterCode, threeLetterCode, nameInPortuguese);
                    } else {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByNameTwoLetterCodeThreeLetterCode(name, twoLetterCode, threeLetterCode);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (nameInPortuguese != null && !nameInPortuguese.isEmpty() && !nameInPortuguese.equals("")) {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByNameTwoLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(name, twoLetterCode, nameInPortuguese);
                    } else {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByNameTwoLetterCode(name, twoLetterCode);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (threeLetterCode != null && !threeLetterCode.isEmpty() && !threeLetterCode.equals("")) {
                    if (nameInPortuguese != null && !nameInPortuguese.isEmpty() && !nameInPortuguese.equals("")) {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByNameThreeLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(name, threeLetterCode, nameInPortuguese);
                    } else {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByNameThreeLetterCode(name, threeLetterCode);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (nameInPortuguese != null && !nameInPortuguese.isEmpty() && !nameInPortuguese.equals("")) {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByNameNameInPortuguese(name, nameInPortuguese);
                    } else {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByName(name);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (twoLetterCode != null && !twoLetterCode.isEmpty() && !twoLetterCode.equals("")) {
                if (threeLetterCode != null && !threeLetterCode.isEmpty() && !threeLetterCode.equals("")) {
                    if (nameInPortuguese != null && !nameInPortuguese.isEmpty() && !nameInPortuguese.equals("")) {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByTwoLetterCodeThreeLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(twoLetterCode, threeLetterCode, nameInPortuguese);
                    } else {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByTwoLetterCodeThreeLetterCode(twoLetterCode, threeLetterCode);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (nameInPortuguese != null && !nameInPortuguese.isEmpty() && !nameInPortuguese.equals("")) {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByTwoLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(twoLetterCode, nameInPortuguese);
                    } else {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByTwoLetterCode(twoLetterCode);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (threeLetterCode != null && !threeLetterCode.isEmpty() && !threeLetterCode.equals("")) {
                    if (nameInPortuguese != null && !nameInPortuguese.isEmpty() && !nameInPortuguese.equals("")) {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByThreeLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(threeLetterCode, nameInPortuguese);
                    } else {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByThreeLetterCode(threeLetterCode);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (nameInPortuguese != null && !nameInPortuguese.isEmpty() && !nameInPortuguese.equals("")) {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findByNameInPortuguese(nameInPortuguese);
                    } else {
                        countryList = countryRepository.findAll();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        if (countryList != null && !countryList.isEmpty()) {
            List<CountryDTO> dtosList = modelMapper.map(countryList, new TypeToken<CountryDTO>() {}.getType());
            return ResponseEntity(dtosList, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new EmptySerializableClass());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }

}
```

**My repository:**

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name LIKE :name")
public List<Country> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.twoLetterCode LIKE :twoLetterCode")
public List<Country> findByTwoLetterCode(@Param("twoLetterCode") String twoLetterCode);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.threeLetterCode LIKE :threeLetterCode")
public List<Country> findByThreeLetterCode(@Param("threeLetterCode") String threeLetterCode);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.nameInPortuguese LIKE :nameInPortuguese")
public List<Country> findByNameInPortuguese(@Param("nameInPortuguese") String nameInPortuguese);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name LIKE :name AND c.twoLetterCode LIKE :twoLetterCode")
public List<Country> findByNameTwoLetterCode(@Param("name") String name, @Param("twoLetterCode") String twoLetterCode);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name LIKE :name AND c.threeLetterCode LIKE :threeLetterCode")
public List<Country> findByNameThreeLetterCode(@Param("name") String name, @Param("threeLetterCode") String threeLetterCode);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name LIKE :name AND c.nameInPortuguese LIKE :nameInPortuguese")
public List<Country> findBynameInPortuguese(@Param("name") String name, @Param("nameInPortuguese") String nameInPortuguese);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.twoLetterCode LIKE :twoLetterCode AND c.threeLetterCode LIKE :threeLetterCode)")
public List<Country> findByTwoLetterCodeThreeLetterCode(@Param("twoLetterCode") String twoLetterCode, @Param("threeLetterCode") String threeLetterCode);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.twoLetterCode LIKE :twoLetterCode AND c.nameInPortuguese LIKE :nameInPortuguese")
public List<Country> findByTwoLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(@Param("twoLetterCode") String twoLetterCode, @Param("nameInPortuguese") String nameInPortuguese);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.threeLetterCode LIKE :threeLetterCode AND c.nameInPortuguese LIKE :nameInPortuguese")
public List<Country> findByThreeLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(@Param("threeLetterCode") String threeLetterCode, @Param("nameInPortuguese") String nameInPortuguese);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name LIKE :name AND c.twoLetterCode LIKE :twoLetterCode AND c.threeLetterCode LIKE :threeLetterCode)")
public List<Country> findByNameTwoLetterCodeThreeLetterCode(@Param("name") String name, @Param("twoLetterCode") String twoLetterCode, @Param("threeLetterCode") String threeLetterCode);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name LIKE :name AND c.twoLetterCode LIKE :twoLetterCode AND c.nameInPortuguese LIKE :nameInPortuguese")
public List<Country> findByNameTwoLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(@Param("name") String name, @Param("twoLetterCode") String twoLetterCode, @Param("nameInPortuguese") String nameInPortuguese);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name LIKE :name AND c.threeLetterCode LIKE :threeLetterCode AND c.nameInPortuguese LIKE :nameInPortuguese")
public List<Country> findByNameThreeLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(@Param("name") String name, @Param("threeLetterCode") String threeLetterCode, @Param("nameInPortuguese") String nameInPortuguese);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.twoLetterCode LIKE :twoLetterCode AND c.threeLetterCode LIKE :threeLetterCode AND c.nameInPortuguese LIKE :nameInPortuguese")
public List<Country> findByTwoLetterCodeThreeLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(@Param("twoLetterCode") String twoLetterCode, @Param("threeLetterCode") String threeLetterCode, @Param("nameInPortuguese") String nameInPortuguese);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name LIKE :name AND c.twoLetterCode LIKE :twoLetterCode AND c.threeLetterCode LIKE :threeLetterCode AND c.nameInPortuguese LIKE :nameInPortuguese")
public List<Country> findByNameTwoLetterCodeThreeLetterCodeNameInPortuguese(@Param("name") String name, @Param("twoLetterCode") String twoLetterCode, @Param("threeLetterCode") String threeLetterCode, @Param("nameInPortuguese") String nameInPortuguese);

@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c")
public List<Country> findAll();
```

So, I guess you guys got it what my question is about. Instead of creating those millions if/else and thousands of queries for handling not-null parameters defined on the URL call, is there a way on Spring Framework - or even on JPA/Hibernate - to write only one query that detects those not-null parameters and search by them (and if all parameters are null, then just return all results)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic spring data jpa repository query with arbitrary AND clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to everyone, but I could do it! It was simple like that:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE (:name is null or c.name LIKE :name)"
+ " AND (:twoLetterCode is null or c.twoLetterCode LIKE :twoLetterCode)"
+ " AND (:threeLetterCode is null or c.threeLetterCode LIKE :threeLetterCode)"
+ " AND (:nameInPortuguese is null or c.nameInPortuguese LIKE :nameInPortuguese)")

public List<Country> findCountries(
@Param("name") String name, 
@Param("twoLetterCode") String twoLetterCode,
@Param("threeLetterCode") String threeLetterCode,
@Param("nameInPortuguese") String nameInPortuguese);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with `@Query` annotations. 
But you can use either Query by Example or Specifications.

With Query by Example you create an instance of your target entity `Country` that contains the filter values as attributes and `null` for those that should not get filtered.
Also provide an `ExampleMatcher` that controls what kind of comparison should be used (equality, contains, case insensitive and so on).

[See the documentation for details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example).

Even more flexible are Specifications where you construct the where condition programmatically using the JPA Criteria API or alternatively using Querydsl.

[Again the documentation describes the details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications).