# Creating Criteria By And or Or on Runtime by JPA Repository

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to create a query by deciding on runtime. Basically I have few parameters and one of them will specify If I should use And or Or to combine criterias. By using Spring JPA Repository how can I do it? It is easy to do it for parameters as :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name IN :names")
List<User> findUserByNameList(@Param("names") Collection<String> names);
```

But if I want to add one more criteria lets say size, and I need to decide which one of (AND,OR) to use to combine criteria, how can I do it?

Example:

```
  SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name IN :names OR/AND size = 10;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic spring data jpa repository query with arbitrary AND clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<User> getUsers(List<String> names, Integer size, boolean useOrPredicate) {

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> user = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);

        Predicate predicate1 = user.get("name").in(names);
        Predicate predicate2 = criteriaBuilder.equal(user.get("size"), size);

        Predicate predicate;

        if(useOrPredicate) 
           predicate = criteriaBuilder.or(predicate1, predicate2);
        else
           predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate1, predicate2);

        criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

        return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```