# How make multi fields filter with JpaRepository and keep pagination

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to make multi fields filter with JpaRepository, but I need to keep pagination(Page).

I tried the following:

```java
Page<Group> getAllByOrganizationAndIdNotInAndLocation_Id(Organization organization, Collection<Long> id, Long location_id, Pageable pageable);
```

However, in some cases, I do not receive all the expect variables and the query does not work as I intended

Comment: Can you please clarify what "In some cases I can receive not all needed variables and this query don't work as I needed." means?

Comment: You write you tried something like, is it what you tried or is it not? Can you submit a minimal working example?

Answer (score 2):

When variables are optional you need to handle their absence. You need to dynamically create your query.
In Spring Data JPA you have three options:

- Criteria API
- QueryDSL
- Query By Example

You can read more on that here: [Dynamic spring data jpa repository query with arbitrary AND clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses)

Answer (score 1):

You may just use this library in combination with Spring's Pageable: https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter

It will let you run search queries such as:

> */search?filter=* **average**(ratings) **>** 4.5 **and** brand.name **in** ('audi', 'land rover') **and** (year **>** 2018 **or** km **<** 50000) and color **:** 'white' **and** accidents **is empty**

Spring's Pageable will let you paginate with `&page=34&size=20`