# How to write dynamic query in JPA repository? Using Java springboot. Is Specification the answer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dynamic, spring-data-jpa

I have a project in JPA repository. I want to retrieve values from two tables using UNIONS and a response parameter and I am having success with the following Native Query.

```
Public interface resultRepository extends JpaRepository<Result, String>{


@Query(value= “SELECT ‘This is from Table 1’ AS MSG, COLUMN1, COLUMN2 COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5 FROM TABLE1 
WHERE COLUMN1 = :column1 AND COLUMN2 = :column2 AND COLUMN3 = :column3 
UNION
SELECT ‘This is from Table 2’ AS MSG, COLUMN1, COLUMN2 COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5 FROM TABLE2
WHERE COLUMN1 = :column1 AND COLUMN2 = :column2 AND COLUMN3 = :column3 ”, nativeQuery = true)
List<Result> getResultByParameters(@Param(“column1”) String column1, 
    @Param(“column2’)String column2,@Param(“column3’) String column3);

}
```

My problem is. I want the “Where” clause to be dynamic. So that they can search by any of these parameters. Whether its column1 and column2 or column2 and column3. In my frontend, these column parameters will be NULL. Using native Query I can't decide to choose what parameters are using what.

I am reading up on Specifications in this link.
https://dimitr.im/writing-dynamic-queries-with-spring-data-jpa

But I just don’t understand it at all. Will I still be able to have a custom Message (MSG)? Or even search on more than one table using a union?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm having the exact issue and followed the same tutorial but I keep running into PropertyReferenceException "No property findAll found for type.." when I try to use repository.findAll(specifications, pageRequest). It should not be this difficult but it's Java so it just is.

Comment: @AlPal 
I couldn't use specifications. Instead I used JPA CriteraBuilder and that solved my issues for dynamic where clauses.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses

Answer (score 6):

So there are many ways to create dynamic queries in JPA. Let's first list few of them down:

1. Custom Repository
2. Specification
3. Custom query in JPA repository itself (which you have already written, but I will show you more flexible workaround for this)
4. QueryDSL

**Custom Repository**

In this approach, basically you create an interface, and declare custom method into it. Then extend this interface to actual repository interface, and implement it manually. This is the most flexible way of working with custom queries. Below is the example:

```
public interface CustomRepository {
    public Result myCustomQueryMethod(String params);
}

public interface ResultRepository extends JpaRepository<Result, Long>, CustomRepository { ... }

public class CustomRepositoryImpl implements CustomRepository {

    @Autowired //@PersistentContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public Result myCustomQueryMethod(String params) {
        String nativeSql = "...";
        // create query, execute it, and transform the results to object using object mapper or manually
    }
}
```

**Specifications**

Next one is the specifications (as you have already mentioned). I will not explain very deep about specifications here, as it is already explained in the tutorial link which you have shared. But yes you can create dynamic queries using specification, if you do not want to write SQLs by yourself. But I guess you cannot have custom projections (custom select clause as you want for MSG parameter) with specifications.

**Custom Query in JPA repository**

Below is the slight modified version of your query, which can serve your purpose if the number of parameters which you want to search (in where clause) are fixed:

```
@Query(value= “SELECT ‘This is from Table 1’ AS MSG, COLUMN1, COLUMN2 COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5 FROM TABLE1 
WHERE (:column1 is null or COLUMN1 = :column1) AND (:column2 is null or COLUMN2 = :column2) AND (:column3 is null or COLUMN3 = :column3)
UNION
SELECT ‘This is from Table 2’ AS MSG, COLUMN1, COLUMN2 COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5 
FROM TABLE2
WHERE (:column1 is null or COLUMN1 = :column1) AND (:column2 is null or COLUMN2 = :column2) AND (:column3 is null or COLUMN3 = :column3) ”, nativeQuery = true)
List<Result> getResultByParameters(@Param(“column1”) String column1, 
@Param(“column2’)String column2,@Param(“column3’) String column3);
```

See what I have done with the where clause there.

**QueryDSL**

It is again similar to Criteria API, but different and more simple syntax. You can create type safe dynamic queries with QueryDSL too. Here is the link which explains QueryDSL in more detail - https://www.baeldung.com/querydsl-with-jpa-tutorial

Comment: OK, I needed to know that I can not have a custom projection using specification.

Comment: Your best bet would be to use either custom repository, or the custom query (#3) in the way which I had mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

e.g. you can change your SQL request where clause as follows

```
WHERE COLUMN1 IN (:column1, :column3, :column3) OR COLUMN2 IN (:column1, :column3, :column3) OR COLUMN3IN (:column1, :column3, :column3)
```

or

```
WHERE (:column1 IS NULL OR COLUMN1 = :column1) OR (:column1 IS NULL OR COLUMN2 = :column2) OR (:column1 IS NULL OR COLUMN3 = :column3)
```

It depends on what logic do you want

Comment: The columns are CHAR's of different sizes, so I would get an error on this.  

INPUT VARIABLE OR PARAMETER NUMBER 7 IS INVALID.