# Delete Query in Spring Boot with Optional Parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to implement Delete query in Spring Boot, however the parameters are optional. How do I write JPA query for same.
Here is how I have implemented for mandate Request Params:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface ABCRepo extends CrudRepository<ABC, Long>{

public List<ABC> findByABCIdAndStartYrAndStartMonth(String pilotId, int startYr, int startMonth);
public long deleteABCByABCId(String pilotId);
}
```

Controller.class

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method= RequestMethod.DELETE)
public Response delete(@PathVariable("abc-id")String pilotId)
{
    LOGGER.info("Trying to delete pilot bank using abc id : "+ abcId);
    long deletedRecords=abcBiz.deleteABCByABCId(abcId);
     if(deletedRecords==0)
     {
        throw new PilotNotFoundException("Entity not found "+abcId);
     }
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).entity(deletedRecords).build();
}
```

My new Controller.class after adding optional params

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method= RequestMethod.DELETE)
public Response delete(@PathVariable("abc-id")String abcId, @RequestParam(name = "bid-yr", required = false)
        int bidYr, @RequestParam(name = "bid-month", required = false) int bidMonth)
{
    LOGGER.info("Trying to delete pilot bank using abc id : "+ abcId);
    long deletedRecords=abcBiz.deleteABCByABCId(a);bcId
     if(deletedRecords==0)
     {
        throw new PilotNotFoundException("Entity not found "+abcId);
     }
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).entity(deletedRecords).build();
}
```

How do I handle this at JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For optional parameters, you need to write the query. Something like below:

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM ABC WHERE abcId=:pilotId AND (:otherOptionalParam IS NULL OR otherField=:otherOptionalParam)")
public long deleteABCByABCId(String pilotId, String otherOptionalParam);
```

If you want to create a complex query, with lot of optional parameters, then you can create custom repository, and develop native queries. Here I have already answered to how we can create custom repositories in Spring data JPA - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68721142/3709922

Comment: Debug and check all the parameter values which are being passed to this repository method. There seems no issue with the query which you have stated in above comment.

Comment: here are the values: ("5422", null, null, null), these values are coming to repository method

Comment: But how come I know that these values exists in your database or not. Check with these values in your database.

Comment: 5422 does exist but there is no column with bidyear or bidabbrev and bidmonth with null matching with 5422.

My question is if incase of null, how can i ignore the fields and only fields which are having value.

Comment: By the above query they are ignored by default. `(:bidYr IS NULL OR startYr=:bidYr)` this will ignore the `startYr` comparison if `bidYr` parameter is `null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237121/discussion-between-lucifer-geralt-and-jignesh-m-khatri).

Answer (score 1):

On Top of what Jignesh has said, don't forget to mark your parameters with Param annotation. Also jpa modification will return int/Integer but not long so I had to change return type too.

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM ABC WHERE abcId=:pilotId AND (:otherOptionalParam IS NULL OR 
otherField=:otherOptionalParam)")
public long deleteABCByABCId(@Param("pilotId")String pilotId, @Param("otherOptionalParam")String 
otherOptionalParam);
```