# Getting Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','", using JPQL

Tags: java, sql, jpql

I have written the following JPQL query. In the query while multiple values(Male, Female etc.) come in the list like gender list or other list. It shows an error in the console like "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','",". Help me out please. Tried a lot to solve.

Query:

```
@Query("""
            SELECT customer_receiver
            FROM SubsidyCustomerUserReceiverEntity customer_receiver
            WHERE customer_receiver.deleted = false
                AND (:isPovertyLineCheck IS NULL OR :isPovertyLineCheck = false OR customer_receiver.isEligible = :isPovertyLineCheck)
                AND (:incomeLowerLimit IS NULL OR :incomeUpperLimit IS NULL OR
                            customer_receiver.receiverGrossHouseholdIncomeAmount BETWEEN :incomeLowerLimit AND :incomeUpperLimit)
                AND (:ageLowerLimit IS NULL OR :ageUpperLimit IS NULL OR
                            customer_receiver.ageYear BETWEEN :ageLowerLimit AND :ageUpperLimit)
                AND ((:locationList) IS NULL OR customer_receiver.area IN (:locationList))
                AND ((:employmentTypeList) IS NULL OR customer_receiver.employmentType IN (:employmentTypeList))
                AND ((:occupationList) IS NULL OR customer_receiver.incomeSourceOrOccupationName IN (:occupationList))
                AND ((:genderList) IS NULL OR customer_receiver.gender IN (:genderList))
            """)
    List<SubsidyCustomerUserReceiverEntity> getEligibleCustomerReceiver(BigDecimal incomeLowerLimit,
            BigDecimal incomeUpperLimit, Integer ageLowerLimit, Integer ageUpperLimit, Boolean isPovertyLineCheck,
            List<String> locationList, List<EmploymentType> employmentTypeList, List<String> occupationList,
            List<String> genderList);
```

I have tried tweaking queries.

Comment: `AND ((:locationList) IS NULL OR customer_receiver.area IN (:locationList))` and other such uses of `List` on the left is not correct, I think.
Instead of having a fixed query, and passing on the burden to check if the parameter is NULL or not and ignore the rest of the conditions on that parameter if it is NULL on the DB is not correct.
Instead of this, use a StringBuilder and keep appending `AND condition` to it in IF blocks if a parameter is NOT NULL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses - Like this - Have a CriteriaBuilder and add keep adding criteria to it only if the parameter is not null

Comment: What I mean to say is, the final query executed should not have `AND (:isPovertyLineCheck IS NULL OR :isPovertyLineCheck = false OR customer_receiver.isEligible = :isPovertyLineCheck)` at all, if `isPovertyLineCheck` is NULL. And like this for all the ANDs. And if it is not-null, then `AND (:isPovertyLineCheck = false OR customer_receiver.isEligible = :isPovertyLineCheck)`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that you have to check.

1. That you are not passing any null value parameter in query.
2. Check there parameter type as well e.g < customer_receiver.isEligible > make sure isEligible and all other parameters types are same.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But that's not the issue. eligibility check is fine. The problem is when multiples values are coming in the list field like :genderList. (:genderList has two values for example Male, Female). when checking :genderList is null, there causes the error I have mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue using JpaSpecification. Thanks all for answering.