# Advanced Custom Query For Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a springboot endpoint where users have an advanced search option. Users are able to put in data they want to filter by, and users can put any amount of restrictions they want (with at least 1).

Here is my DTO:

```
Date date;
String email;
int transactionNumber;
```

In my service layer, I have a stringbuilder that looks like this:

```
public String createQuery(DTO dto){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(Objects.nonNull(dto.getDate())){
        sb.apphend(" AND date = " + dto.getDate() + " ");
    }
}
//... etc till the entire string is made
```

In my repository layer:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user = :user :customQuery", nativeQuery = true)
List<tableEntity> findByAdvancedSearch(@Param("user) String user, @Param("customQuery") String customQuery);
```

I am not sure how to fix this or go about having a repository where I can have a query take a dynamic number of restrictions. Is there a good way to do this?

I tried to use the custom query, since you are able to do a custom number of inputs, but I realize that using the `:variable` command sanitizes the query as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize Dynamic Query with the Specification(JPA) or Query DSL solution. I believe that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses) could be of assistance. You can implement it very easily using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, as demonstrated in the following example:

```
@Service
public class ExampleService {

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    


    public void executeConditionalQuery(boolean condition) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE";
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

        if (condition) {
            sql += " column_name = :value";
            params.put("value", "desired_value");
        } else {
            sql += " another_column = :value";
            params.put("value", "another_desired_value");
        }

        jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, (rs, rowNum) -> {
            // Process the query results here
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```