# How to skip @Param in @Query if is null or empty in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```
@Query(value = "Select f from Documents f " +
        "RIGHT JOIN f.documentStatus ds " +
        "where f.billingAccount.accountId  in :billingAccountIdList " +
        " and ds.statusCode in :paymentStatuses" +
        " and f.paymentDate < :paymentDate")
List<FinancialDocumentEntity> getFinancialDocumentsOverdue(@Param("billingAccountIdList")List<String> billingAccountIdList,
                                                           @Param("paymentStatuses") List<String> paymentStatuses,
                                                           @Param("paymentDate") Date paymentDate);
```

I have query like above. It is possible to skip searching param for example `@Param("paymentStatuses")` in query method if is null or is empty ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data - ignore parameter if it has a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780226/spring-data-ignore-parameter-if-it-has-a-null-value)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try changing

```
" and ds.statusCode in :paymentStatuses"
```

into

```
" and (:paymentStatuses is null or ds.statusCode in :paymentStatuses)"
```

Comment: How it should be if the parameter should be checked as a member?

I tried this but not works: `Select a from MyEntity a where (:groups is null or :groups member of a.groups)`

Comment: same for me.. if i use parameter name twice . it does not works

Comment: Try this: ```" and (:#{#paymentStatuses == null} or ds.statusCode in :paymentStatuses)"```

Comment: This solution will fail if list has more than one item

Comment: Can you please explain what we can do for mongo DB for this specific case ?

Comment: Getting `argument of OR must be type boolean, not type record` in postgres

Answer (score 6):

Try changing

```
" and ds.statusCode in :paymentStatuses"
```

into

```
" and (COALESCE(:paymentStatuses, null) is null or ds.statusCode in :paymentStatuses)"
```

This solution will work for the empty list, null list, and a list with items 1 or more.

Comment: Thanks I solved this oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator error

Comment: for list input is this the correct solution, thanks