# How to ignore null or empty values while using find() in Spring MongoRepository

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, nullable

I have a search functionality where there are different parameters and user can choose one or multiple parameters and ignore other parameters.
I want to use `findByFirstNameAndLastNameAndAddressAndCountry()` for this so that if any parameter is null or empty it can be ignored and the `And` condition get applied to other parameters

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613464/spring-data-mongo-optional-query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

This can be a duplicate issue. You can do it using @Query annotation and your custom Query.

Ref: [How to skip @Param in @Query if is null or empty in Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46789664/how-to-skip-param-in-query-if-is-null-or-empty-in-spring-data-jpa)

```
@Query("select foo from Foo foo where foo.bar = :bar and "
   + "(:goo is null or foo.goo = :goo)")
public List<Foo> findByBarAndOptionalGoo(
     @Param("bar") Bar bar, 
     @Param("goo") Optional<Goo> goo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Query' and 'Criteria' option provided by Spring for MongoDB.

```
Query query = new Query();

if(!obj.getFirstName.isEmpty()){
    Criteria criteria1 = Criteria.where('first_name').is(obj.getFirstName);
    query.add(criteria1);
}
```