# Spring Data JPA - Named query ignoring null parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, option-type

I have the following repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {

    List<Entity> findAllByFirstId(Long firstId);
    List<Entity> findAllBySecondId(Long secondId);
    List<Entity> findAllByFirstIdAndSecondId(Long firstId, Long secondId);
}
```

The constructor implementing an interface generated with `io.swagger:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` uses `Optional<Long>` as optional request parameters (the underlying service uses also the same parameters):

```
ResponseEntity<List<Entity>> entities(Optional<Long> firstId, Optional<Long> secondId);
```

I would like to filter the entities based on the parameters `firstId` and `secondId` which are never `null`s at the database but can be passed through the constructor (the parameter for searching is optional).

The problem comes with the named queries when the `null` is passed as the parameter is optional, the `JpaReposotory` uses the `null` as a criterion for the searching in the database. That's what I don't want - I want to ignore the filtering based on this parameter as long as it is `null`.

My workaround solution based on `Optional` is:

```
public List<Entity> entities(Optional<Long> firstId, Optional<Long> secondId) {

    return firstId
        .or(() -> secondId)
        .map(value -> {
            if (firstId.isEmpty()) {
                return entityRepository.findAllBySecondId(value);
            }
            if (secondId.isEmpty()) {
                return entityRepository.findAllByFirstId(value);
            }
            return entityRepository.findAllByFirstIdAndSecondId(
            firstId.get(), secondId.get());
        })
        .orElse(entityRepository.findAll())
        .stream()
        .map(...)     // Mapping between DTO and entity. For sake of brevity
                      // I used the same onject Entity for both controler and repository 
                      // as long as it not related to the question   

        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This issue has been already asked: [Spring Data - ignore parameter if it has a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780226/spring-data-ignore-parameter-if-it-has-a-null-value) and a ticket created [DATAJPA-209](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-209).

As long as the question is almost 3 years old and the ticket dates back to 2012, I would like to ask if there exists a more comfortable and universal way to avoid the overhead of handling the `Optional` and duplicating the repository methods. The solution for 2 such parameters looks acceptable, however I'd like to implement the very same filtering for 4-5 parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `Specification` utility class like this

```
public class EntitySpecifications {
    public static Specification<Entity> firstIdEquals(Optional<Long> firstId) {// or Long firstId. It is better to avoid Optional method parameters.
        return (root, query, builder) -> 
            firstId.isPresent() ? // or firstId != null if you use Long method parameter
            builder.equal(root.get("firstId"), firstId.get()) :
            builder.conjunction(); // to ignore this clause
    }

    public static Specification<Entity> secondIdEquals(Optional<Long> secondId) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> 
            secondId.isPresent() ? 
            builder.equal(root.get("secondId"), secondId.get()) :
            builder.conjunction(); // to ignore this clause
    }
}
```

Then your `EntityRepository` have to extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository 
    extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Entity> {

}
```

Usage:

```
@Service
public class EntityService {    

    @Autowired
    EntityRepository repository;

    public List<Entity> getEntities(Optional<Long> firstId, Optional<Long> secondId) {
        Specification<Entity> spec = 
            Specifications.where(EntitySpecifications.firstIdEquals(firstId)) //Spring Data JPA 2.0: use Specification.where
                          .and(EntitySpecifications.secondIdEquals(secondId));

        return repository.findAll(spec);        
    }
}
```

Comment: `Specifications` is deprecated as of Spring Data JPA `2.0` and `Specification.where(...)...` shall be used instead.

Comment: @Nikolas Thank for you note. Spring data jpa 2.0 is quite new. In my project 1.0 version is used

Answer (score 2):

> The `io.swagger:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` generates them as
>   `Optional` since I request them as not required (`required: false` by
>   default). I might generate them as boxed types, such as `Long`, …

It’s probably partly a matter of taste. If it were me and I could, I’d go for the version without `Optional`. I don’t think they contribute anything useful here.

```
public List<Entity> entities(Long firstId, Long secondId) {

    List<Dto> dtos;
    if (firstId == null) {
        if (secondId == null) {
            dtos = entityRepository.findAll();
        } else {
            dtos = entityRepository.findAllBySecondId(secondId);
        }
    } else {
        if (secondId == null) {
            dtos = entityRepository.findAllByFirstId(firstId);
        } else {
            dtos = entityRepository.findAllByFirstIdAndSecondId(firstId, secondId);
        }
    }

    return dtos.stream()
        .map(...)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The `Optional` class was designed to be used for return values that may be absent, not really for anything else, so I have read. I think there are rare situations where I’d use them for something else, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use *specifications* instead. See documentation and examples [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications).

Briefly, the idea is following. For each attribute you define a specification. Then check each attribute in your search criteria and if it is not null add corresponding specification to the "concatenated" specification. Then you search using this "concatenated" specification.