# How to perform queries on hierarchical entities using querydsl or spring data jpa specification?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm having an [entity hierarchy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance) like this. Besides some common properties, some properties are shared only by a few subtypes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName

    ... further properties, getters and setters...
}

@Entity
public class Employee extends Person {
    private String salary;

    ... further properties, getters and setters...
}

@Entity
public class BoardMember extends Person {
    private String salary;

    ... further properties, getters and setters...
}

@Entity
public class ExternalMember extends Person {
    private String clearanceLevel;

    ... further properties, getters and setters...
}

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Person> {

}
```

Using QueryDSL I'm trying to search for Persons depending on dynamic filter criterias like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonService {

  @Autowired
  PersonRepository personRepository;

  public Page<Person> search(String firstName, String salary) {
    var searchCriterias = new BooleanBuilder();
    if (firstName != null) {
      searchCriterias.and(QPerson.firstName.eq(firstName));
    }
    if (salary != null) {
        searchCriterias.andAnyOf(
          QPerson.person.as(QEmployee.class).salary.eq(salary),
          QPerson.person.as(QBoardMember.class).salary.eq(salary),
        );
    }
    personRepository.findAll(searchCriterias);
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be the right way, however, I'm getting a lot of errors like "salary" not a member of Person.

What are the various ways to deal with searches for hierarchical entities? I'd prefer QueryDSL for type-safety, but solutions using Spring Data Specification would be fine as well.

edit: The search criterias could get very complex using 15+ different search criterias. So I need a programmatic approach to formulate them.

Comment: I have answered similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60243712/spring-data-jpa-named-query-ignoring-null-parameters/60246119#60246119

Comment: You can use JPA metamodel to make Criteria api type-safe

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi Using the specification api for flat objects is trouble-free. My problem is the hierarchical structure of my entities, which makes criterias much more complex. I need to cast the predicates to multiple subtypes, which hibernate doesn't like.

Comment: isn't the problem here that salary is only known to entities Employee and BoardMember, hence for the PersonRepository it is an unknown field?

Comment: @ManuelJain Yes, this is the problem why hibernate refuses to execute the queries. So how do i programmatically create queries on such fields using querydsl or the criteria api? There are ways to "cast" the QEntities to their Subtype (http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch03.html), but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MattDiMu have you tried changin your repository to 

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Employee>

and use this for executing your findAll operation?

Comment: @ManuelJain Yes, but this doesn't solve as the problem, as this only allows searches for Employees then. I need to search among multiple different subtypes, though!

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce the "not a member of Person" error but I have managed to get the result from your query.

Following [Baeldung's  tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/querydsl-with-jpa-tutorial) and adapting the code from your question I've managed to get the result without errors. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/kasptom/spring-hierarchical-queries/src/master/) is the sample project. Hope this helps

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Person() {
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class BoardMember extends Person {

    @Column
    private String salary;

    public BoardMember(String firstName, String lastName, String salary) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public BoardMember() {
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    public List<Person> search(String firstName, String salary) {
        var searchCriterias = new BooleanBuilder();
        if (firstName != null) {
            searchCriterias.and(QPerson.person.firstName.eq(firstName));
        }
        if (salary != null) {
            searchCriterias.andAnyOf(
                    QPerson.person.as(QEmployee.class).salary.eq(salary),
                    QPerson.person.as(QBoardMember.class).salary.eq(salary)
            );
        }

        var result = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for (Person person : personRepository.findAll(searchCriterias)) {
            result.add(person);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your effort. Unfortunately this doesn't work. It's true, that there is no hibernate exception, but the search doesn't work properly, probably because having 2 salary attributes confuses QueryDSL or Hibernate.
When debugging your application the predicate looks like this: `person.salary eq "salary" || person.salary eq "salary"`, it's unable to differentiate between the different subtypes.

Comment: As the bounty was about to expire, I've awarded it to you as you've provided the closest answer and put much effort into it. Still i cannot flag is correct, as the search doesn't work properly and I don't want to confuse other people with the same problem.