# Passing a null parameter to a native query using @Query JPA annotation

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

In a Spring Boot application, I have a SQL query that is executed on a postgresql server as follows :

```
@Query(value = "select count(*) from servers where brand= coalesce(?1, brand) " +
        "and flavour= coalesce(?2, flavour) ; ",
        nativeQuery = true)
Integer icecreamStockCount(String country, String category);
```

However,

I get the following error when I execute the method :

`ERROR: COALESCE types bytea and character varying in PostgreSQL`

How do I pass String value = null to the query?

**NOTE : ** I found that my question varied from [JPA Query to handle NULL parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554798/jpa-query-to-handle-null-parameter-value)

Comment: I don't know if that's possible or not. I'd try creating separate queries if certain inputs are null.

Comment: FWIW There is no JPA `@Query` annotation. That is Spring.

Comment: you can just change coalesce to `case when then else end`, like `"select count(*) from servers where brand = (case when ?1 = 'undefined' then brand else ?1::bytea) "`

Answer (score 7):

When I encounted this error, I ended up using a combination of `OR` and `CAST` to solve the issue.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM servers
WHERE (?1 IS NULL OR brand = CAST(?1 AS CHARACTER VARYING))
AND (?2 IS NULL OR flavour = CAST(?2 AS CHARACTER VARYING))
```

This works even if `?1`, `?2`, `brand` and `flavor` are all nullable fields.

Note that passing `null` for `?1` means "all servers regardless of brand" rather than "all servers without a brand". For the latter, you could use `IS DISTINCT FROM` as follows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM servers
WHERE (CAST(?1 AS CHARACTER VARYING) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM brand)
AND (CAST(?2 AS CHARACTER VARYING) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM flavour)
```

Finally, certain parameter types such as `Boolean` cannot be cast in SQL from `BYTEA` to `BOOLEAN`, for those cases you need a double cast:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM servers
WHERE (?1 IS NULL OR is_black = CAST(CAST(?1 AS CHARACTER VARYING) AS BOOLEAN))
```

In my eyes this is a problem in Hibernate which could be solved by passing Java `null` parameters as plain SQL `NULL`s rather than interpreting `null` as a value of type `BYTEA`.

Answer (score 6):

You need not coalesce, try this

```
@Query("select count(*) from servers where (brand = ?1 or ?1 is null)" +
        " and (flavour = ?2 or ?2 is null)")
Integer icecreamStockCount(String country, String category);
```

Comment: @Jodiug, do you check it? This is an issue that TS came with.

Comment: Deleted my comment. It seems from my small experiments that `OR` can be performant as long as only a single clause uses data from the database. So `?1 = 3 OR x = ?1` can be indexed but `?1 = x OR x = 22` cannot be indexed. So your answer works according to that rule. My mistake!

Answer (score 2):

So this is not the exact answer to the question above, but I was facing a similar issue, I figured I would add it here, for those that come across this question.

I was using a native query, in my case, it was not a singular value like above, but I was passing in a list to match this part of the query:

```sql
WHERE (cm.first_name in (:firstNames) OR :firstNames is NULL)
```

I was getting the `bytea` error, in the end I was able to send an empty list.

```java
(null == entity.getFirstName()? Collections.emptyList() : entity.getFirstName())
```

In this case, sending the empty list to the resolver worked, where as null did not.

hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use **native query**, there is a problem because it's an improvement not implemented yet, see [hibernate](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13155?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel). If you don't need to use **native** you can do `(where ?1 is null or field like ?1)`. Assuming you do need **native**,
you may treat the String before by setting this empty and then calling the repository and this one would be like:

```
@Query(value = "select count(*) from servers where (?1 like '' or brand like ?1) " +
    "and (?2 like '' or flavour like ?2)",
    nativeQuery = true)
Integer icecreamStockCount(String country, String category);
```

There is always `javax.persistence.EntityManager` bean as option for native query situations and I recommend it instead of previous approach. Here you can append to your query the way you want, as follows:

```
String queryString = "select count(*) from servers ";
if (!isNull(country)) queryString += "where brand like :country";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
if (!isNull(country)) query.setParameter("country", country);
return query.getResultList();
```

Observations:

1. Newer versions have improved this '+' concatenation Strings. But you can build your queryString the way you want with StringBuilder or String Format, it doesn't matter.
2. Be careful with SQL injection, the setParameter method avoid this kind of problem, for more information see this [Sql Injection Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-injection)

Answer (score 0):

null parameters are not allowed before Hibernate 5.0.2.
See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9165
and the replies to https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/6ekbd7dm4d6su5b9i4hsf92ibv4j76n51f@4ax.com