# Spring Data JPA and NULL filter, if Double field value is null nothing is returned

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a data JPA entity where it contains a "price" type Double. Now, the users need to able to filter the records based on that field (Between min and max). Now the problem is, the value in the DB can be null for some records. My data JPA repository uses a native query like "price BETWEEN :priceFrom AND :priceTo". Now, if the user does not specify anything in the filter conditions, all record including the ones where prices is null should be returned. However, this query does not return those record. I know, I can create a new method with query "price IS NULL" and check the filter values in my service layer and call the null version if nothing is specified. But, I have multiple fields with the same requirement then it results in a lot of duplicate methods to maintain. Is there a better approach to handle that situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Query to handle NULL parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554798/jpa-query-to-handle-null-parameter-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me, that you can specify

```sql
(:priceFrom is null and :priceTo is null and price is null)
OR price between :priceFrom and :priceTo
```

if `priceFrom` and `priceTo` are entered, second part of `OR` will be used, otherwise it selects records where `price` is null

Comment: this is helpful but not exactly the same thing I am looking for. If the value is present, null should not be returned. But here, nulls will always be returned,

Comment: late to the party, but you can change as you need to `price is not null` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Spring Data JPA - Specifications should solve this for you. This is a JPA Criteria based solution.
For any complex-enough API – searching/filtering your resources by very simple fields is simply not enough. A query language is more flexible and allows you to filter down to exactly the resources you need. Hence you should easily be able to program for NULL (in the scenario that you currently need) and anything else that you might need.

This is scalable for multiple fields and easy to code/configure. There are a few links which will give you more insight into it

- [Spring Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)
- [Tutorial 1](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications)
- [Tutorial 2](https://dzone.com/articles/java-using-specification)

Hopefully, this is helpful.